# Postgres won't allow ARRAY syntax in COPY

Tags: arrays, postgresql, csv, etl, psycopg2

I have a table with a text array (`text[]`) type column in it. I want to use the `COPY` command to copy a CSV in. I'm using Psycopg2's copy capability, but the question is relevant to Postgres in general.

It seems that Postgres only accepts arrays formatted like `{"string1","string2","string3"}`, not `ARRAY['string1', 'string2', 'string3']` (see below). This is a problem because the string escaping in the former format is a huge pain, and Psycopg2's `mogrify` function outputs arrays in the latter format. Manual escaping in the first format is my last resort, but I really don't want to go there...

Is there any way to make Postgres take the latter format for copying or some other workaround?

Here are my tests:

```
-- proof that both syntaxes are valid and compare equal
db=# SELECT ARRAY['string1', 'string2', 'string3']::text[] = '{"string1","string2","string3"}'::text[];
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

-- COPY works with {} syntax
db=# CREATE TEMP TABLE test(words text[]);
CREATE TABLE
db=# COPY test FROM stdin;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> {"string1","string2","string3"}
>> \.
COPY 1

-- COPY fails with ARRAY syntax
db=# COPY test FROM stdin;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> ARRAY['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
>> \.
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "ARRAY['string1', 'string2', 'string3']"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  COPY test, line 1, column words: "ARRAY['string1', 'string2', 'string3']"
```

Comment: Are you using `mogrify` to generate the file?

Comment: No, I'm passing data into Python's `csv` writer. `mogrify` formats for queries, which have different rules (e.g. single quotes around strings). I did try using `mogrify` just for the array values, but, as I said, it gives me the `ARRAY` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your data a list of tuples:

```
data = [
    (1, ['a','b']),
    (2, ['c','d'])
]
```

Create a `values` syntax template to receive the data tuples:

```
values_template = ','.join(['%s'] * len(data))
```

Place it into a `copy` command:

```
copy_values = "copy (values {0}) to stdout (format csv)".format(values_template)
```

Use `mogrify` to adapt the Python types to Postgresql types:

```
copy_values = cursor.mogrify(copy_values, data)
```

`copy_expert` exports the file:

```
f = open('file.csv', 'wb')
cursor.copy_expert(copy_values, f, size=8192)
f.close()
```

Comment: Ah, solved! This is a cool workaround. Weird that I never thought of it even though I was debugging by copying values to stdout. I've got a `COPY` utility in my Python project that writes to a file to be copied, and I'll change it to do it this way.

Comment: One drawback is that this is slower than Python's `csv` library, at least with my setup (database local on machine).

Answer (score 1):

The first test (the proof) is not really correct. In this case this should be the test:

```
SELECT 'ARRAY["string1", "string2", "string3"]'::text[] = '{"string1","string2","string3"}'::text[]
```

and that does not work. So I would assume no, this format can not be used to COPY FROM stdin.

Comment: The {} syntax expects single quotes surrounding it in a query, and `ARRAY` does not. `SELECT 'ARRAY["string1", "string2", "string3"]'::text[];` returns an error. But {} syntax does not expect single quotes when copying from a CSV.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. When you read it from stdin it behaves as if it was a quoted string, so you end up with an error.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Looks like I'll have to find another way to do this.